Movie about creepy sculptures in a candle lit house, and the sun that never rises
A couple lives in a forest (the girl is blonde with short hair, don't recall anything about the man), and one day they found sculptures of branches and cans, looking like crosses and scarecrows, in front of their house. They find out that these sculptures seems to be famous, but no one knows the identity of the author.
One day the girl finds a hooded figure (certainly the author) dragging around some stuff around the forest, and so they find his house, which is lit only by candles. In the other day, they risk entering the house, but the man gets lost in a tunnel and finds a image in a circle of candles, looking like a ritual. They run home and wait for the sun to rise, but a storm starts and the sun never rises.
I'd guess the movie is American, and dates from 2005 onwards. Can someone help me find out the name of the movie, please?

Just sayin', the sun doesn't actually rise in the real world either.

Of course! For what's it worth, English is not my first language and I was just too lazy to look up a suitable translation for "amanhecer" (portuguese) :P

Sounds like the horror movie Mr. Jones from 2013.

Scott (Jon Foster) and Penny (Sarah Jones) move out to the woods for a year to make a nature documentary. After a few weeks tensions rise as it becomes obvious that the project isn't as well thought out as they had intended. Things begin to look up when Scott's backpack is stolen and they trace the thief to a cabin not far from the one that they are staying in. This new cabin is surrounded by bizarre stick figures and other strange objects.
They go into the cabin and retrieve his backpack. Scott sees that there is a basement, and a sub-basement, and wants to explore more, but Penny persuades him to leave. They realize that this is the home of the almost legendary and mysterious artist, Mr. Jones (Mark Steger).

Mr. Jones is hooded and the heroine, the sculptures and the storm fit your description. The trailer:




Very efficient, sir! Thanks.
